# Sudden Audio Balance Issue On 4K iMac

Tags: audio, imac, headphones

I am partially deaf in one ear and require the use of the accessibility feature of "Audio Balance" when using headphones and over the past 48 hours I've noticed a big problem with my iMac 4K.

Whenever I turn the volume up or down it's changing the balance level with each click of the volume. So when I turn the volume up it's moving the balance further to the right and away from the left side instead of leaving the balance level as I selected and then changing the master volume which in turn allows me to listen to audio centred at any volume.

I know it's nothing to do with my hearing as I have the exact same balance on my MacBook Air and it is not having the same trouble of moving the balance when the volume is turned up or down.

You can see in the photos below that the balance slider is missing from the "Master Stream" section and the Master Volume is greyed out and it's just adjusting to left/right volume, while the bottom picture is what my MacBook Air which has the balance working perfectly and leaving the balance as I selected and just adjusting the master volume while leaving the left/right volume untouched.

iMac 4K
[image]

MacBook Air (Balance Working Perfectly and has Balance Slider In MIDI App)
[image]

I have no idea how this changed, I've tried restarting, resetting SMC/PRAM and just this morning did a full clean install and Time Machine backup and it's still there. Does anyone know how I can get it back to way it is on my MacBook Air.

I've installed no new software or anything like that the only thing I've done in past few days is installing the latest 11.2.1 update.

I am using the exact same headphones in both examples so I know it can't be that. I've also noticed that it says "External Headphones" for the MacBook Air which is working perfectly, while the troublesome iMac 4K has the headphones listed as "Built-In Output". Could this be contributing?

Any help is greatly appreciated as this is very annoying for someone with partial hearing loss.

Comment: I don't have a laptop to check against, but on my Mac Pro I see exactly the behaviour you describe for the iMac - however, the 4 sliders are fully interactive. Adjusting balance or either one of the individual volume sliders changes the others. After that changing the Output volume (in Sound not in Audio/Midi as that's greyed out same as yours) then adjusts the volume of both output channels & maintains the difference between them. Testing on an output with an independent volume control & mono sound source shows the balance is preserved at all volumes.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that the l/r sliders in the Audio/MIDI section keep moving whenever the output volume goes up or down. If I am turning up the volume my headphones sound like it keeps moving to the right and when I turn the volume down it sounds like it moves to the left. This is not happening on my MacBook Air so I am certain it is an issue with the iMac itself and it certainly wasn't happening in the past. I am at a loss as to how this could've happened I have done nothing and even done a full clean install.

Comment: 'keep moving' doesn't really tell me enough. They should move similarly, though they will appear to space wider as it gets louder (laws of acoustics, too much to explain here). I tested on a studio-grade monitoring system that the balance stays in exactly the same place audibly.

Comment: Test. Set the Output volume to half way (-20db) then shift one fader in audio/midi to -30db. Turn the Output up to 0db, the 2nd channel should show -15, then slide down until the louder channel hits -30dB. the 2nd channel should read -38dB. This is "correct" behaviour.

Comment: Basically on both my iMac and MacBook I have the balance slider around 10% to the right to counter my hearing loss but recently on my iMac whenever I turn the volume up it sounds like I am moving the balance slider gradually to the right as it gets louder and when I turn the volume down it feels like I am moving the balance slider to the left. This is not the case when I am using my MacBook Air which keeps it's balance whenever I change the volume

Comment: That is not the correct behaviour though as it's not what occurs on my MacBook it certainly didn't do on my iMac until around 2 days ago. When I test the exact same conditions on my MacBook turning up the volume does not sound like I am moving the balance to the right.

Comment: Did you actually try my test yet? As we can't hear your headset we need some numbers to go on. Once you've done the test, you should repeat it inverted (the other side louder) & see if you get the same numbers.

Comment: Yep I tried the test and exactly what you describe happens. However the headphones still sound like whenever I turn the volume up the audio moves to the right and when I turn down the audio sounds like it's balancing to the left.

Comment: I'm not complaining and apologies if I sound like I am but it's just so annoying and as you can see in the MacBook screenshot that there is actually a slider inside the Audio/MIDI and that the l/r are greyed out and cannot be moved. I am sure this has something to do with it because I am having zero issues on my MacBook with my headphones sounding like audio is moving to the right whenever the volume is turned up.